# How to have 2 interdependant modules with their own config in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am an Eclipse user having metaphysical question before fully switching to IntelliJ.

I have 2 Maven modules:

- "main" module which is my main app which uses
- "shared" module which is shared by misc applications

**I'd like to:**

1. work at the same time on both modules, meaning the changes in "shared" code would be automatically picked by my main app when I run it.
   Ideally I would not have to be forced to create & install in my .m2 folder the artifact "shared-SNAPSHOT.jar" for my main app to use the updated code.
2. be able to work independantly on each one (own .idea containing each it's own launchconfiguration) while sharing in their own respective git repo their own configuration. It would mean:

   - each can have it's own set of launchconfigurations (the folders in the .idea where are defined the launch configurations)
   - each would have it's own code formatter setting
     => with this requirement, I want a new dev to be able to just git clone one project and work on it directly with minimal configuration.

**What I managed to do:**

If I open the "main" module with a .idea preconfigured inside it is ok: I directly have my formatter & my launch configs.
BUT if I then try to open the "shared" module, IntelliJ proposes:

- either to open in a new window. The problem is then that I have to INSTALL the shared-SNAPSHOT.jar in my .m2 repo in order for the updated code to be seen by my main app. Is there any way for 2 IntelliJ windows to 'see' the code from one another ?
- or to keep the same window, BUT it adds a new config for the imported "shared" module inside "main"'s .idea folder. Which I don't want because I'd like "main" module to be unaware of "shared" (apart from the maven dependency). And I don't want to force any colleague working on "main" to be forced to also import "shared".

Do you have a best practise for me or should I stay with Eclipse ;) ?

Comment: Do you really mean `DEPLOY`, rather than `INSTALL`? As in `mvn clean install`, which builds the snapshot and installs it locally in `~/.m2/repository` for access by other projects.

Comment: You're right Steve, thanks ! I corrected my question.

Comment: Since run configurations and code style settings are stored per project (vs per module), you can't achieve what you want in IntelliJ IDEA. You either have 2 different projects in 2 separate frames, or you have one project with 2 modules, but the configuration is the same for both.